# GraphDB undirected graph path search

Tags: shortest-path, graphdb

GraphDB 9.9 introduced the powerful feature for retrieving paths (shortests paths, cycles etc.)

However, from the documentation it is not clear whether this can also be used for nondirected graphs - i.e. ignoring the edge directions given by triples.

Is it possible to apply the path search functions without considering edge direction (e.g. in social networks where most relationships are mutual). Of course duplicating each edge with its inverse version can be a solution but far from elegant.

Comment: It seems that GraphDB 9.10 will also support this use case

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem was partly solved in GraphDB 9.10 which now provides the path:bidirectional setting to enable a nondirected path search.

However the returned arcs do not reflect their natural (stored) direction - i.e. some arcs will be returned reverted, depending on how the path serch algorithm navigated them. Something that limits the value of the results, since the query client will not be able to guess how to use the identified path in further SPARQL queries.